# Grass feed rust stains on concrete

Tags: concrete, staining, stain-removal

Applied recently "Scotts® Green MAX™ Lawn Food" to my lawn without knowing that the iron could stain my driveway concrete and ended up with some very ugly rust stains after the rain came down later that day.

Here are my questions:

1. Can I expect that the stains will wash off over time simply by being exposed to the elements like rain and snow and if so how long could that take?
2. If not which product would you recommend to remove the stains? So far I tried [ZEP Calcium, Lime and Rust Remover](http://www.homedepot.com/p/ZEP-128-oz-Calcium-Lime-and-Rust-Remover-ZUCAL128/100670176) found at Home Depot and it did not help a lot.
3. Since there are already some chips in the concrete that would be nice to fix, would it make sense to get a contractor to coat the concrete with a thin layer which would also cover the rust stains and how much does that cost per 1000 sqft?

Comment: I have had trouble with rust from both metal filings and a bag of furtilizer both gave me a hard time to remove. I usually use muriatic acid to etch the stains out of cement, this did not work but a product called CLR , calcium lime and Rust did help but it took 3 or 4 big bottles to clean it up. Maybe similar to ZEP. Give it a try but expect to use several times and a scrub brush.

Comment: Thanks Ed, did you use this one: http://www.homedepot.com/p/CLR-1-Gal-Calcium-Lime-and-Rust-Remover-4-Case-CL4/100670293?

Comment: Yes that is what I used it did work.

Answer (score 1):

CLR is what you're looking for. I had a similar problem as you (I was cutting metal on my driveway and did not sweep up the fines that night...Rusted the next day!) and it worked like a charm. It comes in a grey bottle with a multicoloured label.

Dilute using the measurements on the bottle, and scrub hard with a stiff bristled broom. Rinse well.  This stuff is awesome elsewhere in the house too - in particular to clean up around taps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this one in specific http://www.homedepot.com/p/CLR-1-Gal-Calcium-Lime-and-Rust-Remover-4-Case-CL4/100670293

Comment: I was gone for a week with the metal filings it was horrible, the bag of lawn food was easy compared to the week old metal filings. the CLR did the trick.